# Cakephp Application is not running on the server

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I have uploaded a cakephp project into my web-server. Several Application is already running there.But my added new project is not running.In firefox it returns "Connection was reset". In Safari, it returs empty page. Where should i change in my project or server?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs for the site?  Have you set debug to 2?

Comment: make sure re_write module is enabled on web server

Comment: rewrite module is enabled and there is no error in error log...